# Can't establish the URL of Bot Builder files stored in Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am developing a chatbot using NodeJS and BotBuilder. I have the file chatbot.jpg stored in a folder named image. This sits just beneath the root directory. I am able to display the image (using Kudu to find the URL) in a web browser as follows:

https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/images/chatbot.jpg

If I remove the .scm element within the URL, I can no longer display the image.

Even more curiously, if I use the above URL in my bot code, the image doesn't display.

```
var welcomeCard = new builder.HeroCard(session)
.title("This is the new")
.subtitle('Virtual Assistant')
.images([
new builder.CardImage(session)
.url("http://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/images/chatbot.jpg")
alt("Virtual Assistant")
]);
session.send(new builder.Message(session)
.addAttachment(welcomeCard));
```

My question is, how do I find out the regular URL of the image stored in the Azure App Service, so that I can use it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

From the public web, the URL should be https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/images/chatbot.jpg

The wwwroot folder is the root folder served by the app service.

Your code can't just the scm URL as that URL requires you to be logged in to the Azure portal; it's an admin URL.

Comment: Tried that. I get the following: {"code":"NotAuthorized","message":"/images/chatbot.jpg"} on this URL: https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/images/chatbot.jpg. This sounds like an authentication problem. However, I can access the bot and it runs nicely on Messenger. So I'm unsure what to do next.

Comment: That implies that you have authentication switched on somewhere; it should be the correct URL, an anonymous user is just not allowed to access it.

Comment: Just checked in portal.azure. In Settings/Authentication, App Service Authentication is set to off. And yes, it isn't "mysite".

Comment: Well, there's more than one way to have auth... It's your node server set up to serve static files to anonymous users? Or have you configured the IIS proxy to serve static assets? It looks like you need to go back to basics in your setup...

Comment: Good question. I'm using the azure portal and set up a node JS app service, so the only place I can see authentication settings are those I previously mentioned. If I change the URL to an external site, it works just fine.

Comment: Okay. So, the question is no longer "what is the URL", it's "how do I configure node in Azure to serve static assets". I don't know the answer, but if you Google that you are bound to find the details. It may not directly be auth, that may be a side effect. Suggest you close this question and explore the other one.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your goal, you need to configure your Restify server to [serve static files](http://restify.com/#serve-static).

Example Restify config (add to your bot code):

```
server.get(/\/images\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
  directory: './images'
}));
```

Comment: Tried the above. Still not working. Also tried  directory: __dirname and again no luck.

Comment: What is strange is that when I upload the following code to the Azure App Service, the first time I run the bot, the image shows. Successive runs don't display the image.  server.get(/\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    directory: __dirname,
    default: 'index.html',
   match: /^((?!app.js).)*$/  source
}));